# Protocol extension to struct and overwritable

Tags: swift, properties, static, overriding, protocols

I want to be able to decode different objects that come from the server with different date formats and for that I came up with this protocol:

```
public protocol DateFormatProtocol{
    var dateFormat : String {get}
}

public protocol CodableWithDateFormat : Codable, DateFormatProtocol{
    static var dateFormat: String {get}// = "DatFormat"
}

public extension CodableWithDateFormat{
    public static var dateFormat: String { return "Base date format" }
}
```

So when I need to I could override the property in each struct that needs a different date format but I don't want eavery struct to override the default date format given on the extension of the protocol. Is there any way for me being able to write this? :

```
struct Struct1 : CodableWithDateFormat{
    var dateFormat: String { return "Overwritten Date Format" }
    let prop1 : String
    let prop2 : Int
}

struct Struct2 : CodableWithDateFormat{ //Type 'Struct2' does not conform to protocol 'DateFormatProtocol'
    let prop1 : String
    let prop2 : Int
}
```

Comment: You forget to include `DateFormatProtocol` declaration that could help the readers to provide a better fix..

Comment: You're right, I edited the question

Comment: Please check the updated answer.

Comment: Is there a way that, when implementing the Protocol CodableWithDateFormat the compiler will force the struct to have dateFormat property?

Comment: Actually if you remove the default implementation from extension it will force then. Or if you use DateFormateProtocol then it is possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to match the declaration for `dateFormat` in `DateFormatProtocol` as below,

```
public protocol DateFormatProtocol {
    static var dateFormat: String { get }
}

public protocol CodableWithDateFormat: Codable, DateFormatProtocol {}

public extension CodableWithDateFormat {
    public static var dateFormat: String { return "Base date format" }
}

struct Struct1: CodableWithDateFormat {
    public static var dateFormat: String { return "Overwritten Date Format" }
    let prop1: String
    let prop2: Int
}

struct Struct2: CodableWithDateFormat {
    let prop1: String
    let prop2: Int
}
```

Comment: Man this really helped me. Thanks